# Template specialization for std::less in C++11, using a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl, eigen

I have a Matrix class that derives from an Eigen template:

```
template<typename T,
         int _Rows = Eigen::Dynamic,
         int _Cols = Eigen::Dynamic>
class Matrix : public Eigen::Matrix<T, _Rows, _Cols>
```

I need to use this type as a key for an `std::map` container, hence I need a comparator object. I would like to specialize `std::less` for this purpose. A draft version that does not compile looks like this, to get you the idea:

```
template<typename Matrix<typename T,
                         int _Rows = Eigen::Dynamic,
                         int _Cols = Eigen::Dynamic> > >
struct less
{
    bool operator()(const Matrix<T,
                                 Rows,
                                 Cols>& lhs,
                    const Matrix<T,
                                 Rows,
                                 Cols>& rhs) const;
    {
      Matrix<T,
             Rows,
             Cols>::const_iterator lhsIt = lhs.begin();
      Matrix<T,
             Rows,
             Cols>::const_iterator rhsIt = rhs.begin();
      for (;
           lhsIt != lhs.end();
           ++lhsIt, ++rhsIt)
      {
        if (*lhsIt < *rhsIt)
        {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
};
```

The problem is that I want to specialize `std::less` using a template. What is a correct way to code this ? Do I have to resort to template specialization ?

I will also need to specialize `std::hash` in a similar way to be able to use `std::map`.

Comment: `template<typename T, int _Rows, int _Cols>
struct less<Matrix<T, _Rows, _Cols> >`

Comment: What if you just implement less operator inside your Matrix class? It is enough to use it as a key in map

Comment: @TomKnapen except that `_Rows` and `_Cols` are reserved identifiers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The problem is that I want to specialize `std::less` using a template.

Don't. `std::less` means "call the `<` operator" for this class"; specializing it for a class with no `<` operator is needlessly confusing to others reading your code, and specializing it for a class with a `<` operator is pointless.

Just implement a correct `operator<` overload, and you can use it in `std::map`.

> I will also need to specialize `std::hash` in a similar way to be able to use `std::map`.

No, you don't. That's only needed for `unordered_map`.

By the way, your comparison algorithm is wrong. It reports `[2, 1] < [1, 2]` **and** `[1, 2] < [2, 1]`. Not to mention that it doesn't handle the case when the two matrices have different numbers of elements.

Comment: Stepanov and McJones distinguish between `<` and `std::less` in Elements of Programming. They use `std::less` as a *default total ordering* for types which might not have a *natural total ordering*, e.g. complex numbers (though AFAIK `std::complex` does not provide such a specialization, the specialization for pointers is well-known).

Comment: Thank you for your advices. The implementation was straightforward. I also added the test case *lhsIt > *rhsIt in the comparison. The comparison between matrices of various sizes is not needed at the moment.

Comment: @dyp I personally see the `less` etc. specializations for pointers as more of a patch for core language brokenness, just like `div` is in large part a patch for the broken division/modulo operators in C89/C++98.

Answer (score 6):

The correct syntax is

```
template <typename T, int Row, int Col>
struct less<Matrix<T, Row, Col>>
{
    bool operator()(const Matrix<T, Row, Col>& lhs,
                    const Matrix<T, Row, Col>& rhs) const
    {
        // implementation:
        return lexicographical_compare(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
    }
};
```

which is a specialization.

BTW, your implementation doesn't respect less requirement: (it is not symmetric).

Comment: Thank you for the description of the partial specialization.

Comment: Nice use of `lexicographical_compare` (+1).